# eloquent multiple nested lets in kotlin

Tags: android

I have the following code, I'm finding it a bit redundant, is there a better way of handling this scenario using built-in extensions?

These arguments are passed by the Navigation Controller

```
arguments?.let { t ->
    t.getString("username")?.let {
        products = getProducts(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the first `let` since you are invoking only one method on it.
Furthermore you don't need to assign `products` inside since `let` returns it anyway.

```kotlin
products = arguments?.getString("username")?.let { getProducts(it) }
```